# Sharing filter weight in convolution network

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have been working on VGG16 for image recognition for quite a while, and I am very confident about it already. Today, I came across a [post](https://www.quora.com/Are-convolutional-neural-networks-related-to-the-convolution-of-two-functions-in-mathematics) in Quora and I started to doubt my understanding on CNN.

In that post, it says that the same filter in a CNN layer should share the same weight. So, assume the kernal size is 3 and the number of filter is 1 in the following constitutional layer, the total number of parameters (weights) should be 3X1 = 3, which is represented by the red, blue, and green arrows. It's easy to understand the Conv1d example.

[image]

Then, I try to do experiment on Conv2d with the following keras code:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
input_layer = Input(shape=(100,100,1,), name='input_layer')
ccm1_conv = Conv2D(filters=1,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1),padding='same')(input_layer)
model = Model(input_layer,ccm1_conv)
model.summary()

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 100, 100, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_9 (Conv2D)            (None, 100, 100, 1)       10        
=================================================================
Total params: 10
Trainable params: 10
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Since I use only `1 filter`, and my `kernel_size = 3X3`, which means that the kernel reads `9 neurons` in the previous layers and then connect it to a neuron in the next layer. Therefore, I would expect `9 parameters` (weights) instead of `10`.

Then, I tried `number of filters = 10`, `kernal_size = 5X5`, it gives `260 parameters` (weights) instead of `5*5*10 parameters` that I would expect:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout
from keras.models import Model
input_layer = Input(shape=(100,100,1,), name='input_layer')
ccm1_conv = Conv2D(filters=60,kernel_size=(3,3),strides=(1,1))(input_layer)
model = Model(input_layer,ccm1_conv)
model.summary()

_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_layer (InputLayer)     (None, 100, 100, 1)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_10 (Conv2D)           (None, 100, 100, 10)      260       
=================================================================
Total params: 260
Trainable params: 260
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

It seems the number of parameters in Conv2d is calculated by the following equation

> num_weights = num_filters * (kernal_width*kernal_height + 1)

And I have no idea where does the +1 come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *+1* comes from the bias term of each filter. In addition to the kernel weights, each filter has an extra parameter called the bias term (which multiplies a constant 1), like in a fully-connected layer. Keras uses a bias term for each filter by default, but you can also omit it by setting the argument `use_bias` of [Conv2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) to `False`:

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, Dropout
from keras.models import Model

input_layer = Input(shape=(100, 100, 1,), name='input_layer')
ccm1_conv = Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same', use_bias=False)(input_layer)
model = Model(input_layer, ccm1_conv)
model.summary()
```